# Change of Currency sign in the salesforce

Tags: salesforce

Can we change the echo sign in the Sales force?I mean to say that i want to change the $ sign on the currency data type into Rupee sign .Is it possible? if yes then how.

Answer (score 0):

Set:

> Currency Locale

under Setup | Company  Information

This can also be configured on a user by user basis.